# Shoes 4 ,Cannot call objects outside main app

Tags: ruby, shoes

Im developing a really simple application in Ruby and decided to use Shoes Gui, im trying to use the new fourth version but i cannot call shoes objects outside the app, for example in the Shoes Manual http://shoesrb.com/manual/Rules.html this code doesn't work:

```
 class Messenger
   def initialize(stack)
     @stack = stack
   end
   def add(msg)
     @stack.append do
       para msg
     end
   end
 end
```

when i pass the stack object from the app nothing happens, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed out reading the manual completely. The manual very clearly says that this could apparently should work but it doesn't since the App object isn't around any more. Fortunately, each shoes object has a app method, so:
You should replace your code with:

```
class Messenger
 def initialize(stack)
  @stack = stack
 end
 def add(msg)
  @stack.app do
   @stack.append do
     para msg
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue described here, but with the right piece of code from the manual. I have found something, so I'm posting it here, hoping it'll help someone (or that someone will explain me what I've *not* found).

Here is what I had first (it doesn't work, no matter where you put your class instantiation).

```
class Messenger
 def initialize(stack)
  @stack = stack
 end
 def add(msg)
  @stack.app do
    @stack.append do
        para msg
    end
  end
 end
end

 Shoes.app do
    stack margin: 20, width: 20 do
        subtitle "Shoes box"
        para "Maaamaaaaa"

        button "Mama ?" do
            s = Messenger.new(@box)
            s.add("Yeah, mama !")
        end
    end
    @box = stack
 end
```

First thing : if you got these two pieces of code in the same file, you could do that :

```
class Messenger
 ...
  @stack.app do
    @box.append do
        para msg
    end
  ...
end
```

It works.

It doesn't work if you remove the `@stack.app do` block or if you move this class in another file though. If you put your class instantiation somewhere else, it doesn't work either.

More interesting, now, and working even if you put your Messenger class somewhere else, you can do that :

```
class Messenger
 ...
 def add(msg)
  @stack.app do
        para msg
  end
 ...


 Shoes.app do
    ...
        button "Mama ?" do
            @box.append do
                s = Messenger.new(@box)
                s.add("Yeah, mama !")
            end
        end
    ...
 end
```

Now you also can move your class instantiation anywhere in your app block... but it still has to be  BEFORE the box you're trying to append to, and that same box has to be declared BEFORE the button which is trying to add to it. Making the thing a bit tricky. Otherwise, you can let your class instantiation here. It means you will create a new object every time you're trying to append something to your box. And it is ugly. But it works.

Edit : just saw that, you can replace the `@stack.append` do by `self.append do` in the Messenger class. Though it doesn't really append anything, since it's adding the msg at the begining of your window.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change `class Messenger` to `class Messenger < Shoes`. This is essential for any and all classes in Shoes. Then, put the `Shoes.app` statement after the `end` statement of the class, but don't add the `do`. Your code should look like this:

```rb
class Messenger < Shoes
    # Your code goes here...
end
Shoes.app [styling goes here]
```

NOTE: Put the `Shoes.app` only once, at the end, after all classes have been defined.